# Edit regex strings in Python using format method

Tags: python, regex

I want to develop a regex in Python where a component of the pattern is defined in a separate variable and combined to a single string on-the-fly using Python's `.format()` string method. A simplified example will help to clarify. I have a series of strings where the space between words may be represented by a space, an underscore, a hyphen etc. As an example:

```
new referral
new-referal
new - referal
new_referral
```

I can define a regex string to match these possibilities as:

```
space_sep = '[\s\-_]+'
```

(The hyphen is escaped to ensure it is not interpreted as defining a character range.)

I can now build a bigger regex to match the strings above using:

```
myRegexStr = "new{spc}referral".format(spc = space_sep)
```

The advantage of this method for me is that I need to define lots of reasonably complex regexes where there may be several different commonly-occurring stings that occur multiple times and in an unpredictable order; defining commonly-used patterns beforehand makes the regexes easier to read and allows the strings to be edited very easily.

However, a problem occurs if I want to define the number of occurrences of other characters using the `{m,n}` or `{n}` structure. For example, to allow for a common typo in the spelling of 'referral', I need to allow either 1 or 2 occurrences of the letter 'r'. I can edit `myRegexStr` to the following:

```
myRegexStr = "new{spc}refer{1,2}al".format(spc = space_sep)
```

However, now all sorts of things break due to confusion over the use of curly braces (either a `KeyError` in the case of `{1,2}` or an `IndexError: tuple index out of range` in the case of `{n}`).

Is there a way to use the `.format()` string method to build longer regexes whilst still being able to define number of occurrences of characters using `{n,m}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can double the `{` and `}` to escape them or you can use the old-style string formatting (`%` operator):

```py
my_regex = "new{spc}refer{{1,2}}al".format(spc="hello")
my_regex_old_style = "new%(spc)srefer{1,2}al" % {"spc": "hello"}

print(my_regex)           # newhellorefer{1,2}al
print(my_regex_old_style) # newhellorefer{1,2}al
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks.